# Problema en conexión BD POO php

Tags: php, sql, poo

espero que me puedan ayudar ya que e estado intentando conectarme a mi BD por POO y hasta el momento no he podido hacerlo estos son los errores que me arroja
Gracias!

```
Aviso : Variable no definida: conexion_db en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ PROYECTOS \ PDO \ conexion.php en la línea 13

Aviso : Intentando obtener la propiedad 'connect_errno' de un no objeto en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ PROYECTOS \ PDO \ conexion .php en la línea 15

Error fatal : Error no detectado: Llamada a una función miembro set_charset () en nulo en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ PROYECTOS \ PDO \ conexion.php: 23 Seguimiento de pila: # 0 C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ PROYECTOS \ index.php (35): Conexión -> __ construct () # 1 C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ PROYECTOS \ index.php (47): ConsultaDatos -> __ construct () # 2 {main} lanzado en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ PROYECTOS \ PDO \ conexion.php en la línea 23
```

```
//constantes conexion base de datos config.php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'stevbel');

define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

```
//archivo conexion.php

require('config.php');

class Conexion{

protected $conexion_db;

public function __construct(){

$this->$conexion_db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if($this->conexion_db->connect_errno){

echo "Fallo la conexion ". $this->conexion_db->connect_errno;

return;
}


$this->conexion_db->set_charset(DB_CHARSET); 
}

}
```

```
//archivo index.php
require('PDO/conexion.php');

Class ConsultaDatos extends Conexion{

public function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
}

public function getdatos(){
$resultado = $this->conexion_db->query("SELECT * FROM servicios");


$producto = $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
return $producto;
}
}

$producto= new ConsultaDatos();
$arrayDatos = $producto->getdatos();

foreach($arrayDatos as $elemento)
        {
            var_dump($elemento);

        }
```

Comment: Saludos. Considerando que se indica que `Intentando obtener la propiedad 'connect_errno'`  como linea *15* el `Variable no definida: conexion_db` corresponde a tu `if($this->conexion_db->connect_errno)` más arriba estas inicializando `$this->$conexion_db` no `$this->conexion_db`; espero te sirva de pista para los demas errores; aquí no se aprecia que línea de código corresponde.

Comment: En otras palabras, has cometido un error al escribir `$this->$conexion_db`, te esta sobrando el segundo `$`.